# How to connect VMware Workstation on local network to access a database server?

Tags: database, linux, vmware-workstation, linux-networking

**Environment**

Host OS: Win7 x64
VMware Workstation: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 running a Teradata database server.

**Details**

I've mounted a demo [Teradata Express for VMware](http://developer.teradata.com/database/articles/introduction-to-teradata-express-for-vmware-player) database server on my local machine and am trying to connect to the Teradata database server on the VM image.

The VM:

- Can connect to the internet.
- Is network connected via a Bridged network.

The Host:

- Can see the VMware Network Adapter (using an ipconfig /all)

From here, how can I connect to the VM from my local machine (host) to the VM's Teradata database server to query for data? I'm not asking what to use for a connection string; rather, what else would I need to make the connection work?

Comment: What's not working about it now?  Sounds like the VM and the host are on the same network segment via the bridge - what issue are you having with the connection?

Comment: @Shane - I've never used Linux. I've button mashed my way to at least being able to spin up the database server. How can I even tell that I can connect into the VM from the host?

Comment: You'll want to check what the IP configuration looks like on the VM (`ifconfig`), and use that address to try to connect to (ping it first, then attempt to connect to the database).

Comment: I've tried pinging the IP from ifconfig: 192.168.1.10. Pinging results in a "request time out". Here's the ifconfig results: `inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0` and `inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fec0:ae34/64 Scope:Link`

Answer (score 1):

Is your Host system able to connect to the DB server? The VM system should be seamless on the network if you configured your VM adapter to use NAT. If you chooses Bridge Network type then there are other things to check.

If you are using NAT, make sure from your VM you can ping your Win System. If that works, then there should not be any reason you can't connect. Because that is as if you are connecting from your Win System.

If you are using Bridge, That means your VM system has a unique IP on the same network as your Win system. The DB server will treat it as a new system, then you need to look at the configuration on the BD server as well, some DB server may exclude on IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall configuration in Yast. If it allows connection the server port, that you just need to connect to guestIP:port.

If the firewall on Suse is not running, it could be that your windows firewall prevents the connection. Check this as well.

Comment: I just checked Yast > Firewall and the Current Status = "Firewall is not running".